# Fetching JSON data when getting data using AJAX and PHP with json_encode method

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am getting data from php using ajax call but data is looking like as following. This data I am getting using *"json_encode"* method. I am here getting data using ajax call. Can anyone please help me to retrieve data from this string.

```
"[
   {
     "Id":"1",
     "Title":"Image1",
     "Description":"Image1",
     "CreatedDate":"2016-09-05 23:41:42",
     "Order":"1",
     "PhotoUrl":"https://www.enterprise.ca/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/CHRY_200_2015.png"
    },
   {
     "Id":"2",
     "Title":"Image2",
     "Description":"Image2",
     "CreatedDate":"2016-09-05 23:41:42",
     "Order":"1",
     "PhotoUrl":"https://www.enterprise.ca/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/CHRY_200_2015.png"
    },
   {
     "Id":"3",
     "Title":"Image3",
     "Description":"Image3",
     "CreatedDate":"2016-09-05 23:41:42",
     "Order":"1",
     "PhotoUrl":"https://www.enterprise.ca/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/CHRY_200_2015.png"
    },
   {
     "Id":"4",
     "Title":"Image4",
     "Description":"Image4",
     "CreatedDate":"2016-09-05 23:41:42",
     "Order":"1",
     "PhotoUrl":"https://www.enterprise.ca/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/CHRY_200_2015.png"
    },
   {
     "Id":"5",
     "Title":"Image5",
     "Description":"Image5",
     "CreatedDate":"2016-09-05 23:41:42",
     "Order":"1",
     "PhotoUrl":"https://www.enterprise.ca/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/CHRY_200_2015.png"
    },
]";
```

My PHP Code is like as follows :

```
$resultSet=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from gallery");
$rows=array();
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet)){
$rows[]=$r;
}
echo json_encode($rows,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: if that is the output your php is generating that is invalid JSON, the ending `;` would be seen as an invalid token, and the surrounding quotes around the array would make the whole thing be treated as a string

Comment: not a valid json,check in jsonlint.json_encode() always give you a valid json..

Comment: show some code you tried to generate this and you requirement too!!!

Comment: I have added some more code for PHP

Comment: try print_r(json_encode($rows,true));

Comment: Now I am getting following output 

"[{"Id":"1","Title":"Image1","Description":"Image1","CreatedDate":"2016-09-05 23:41:42","Order":"1","PhotoUrl":"https:\/\/www.enterprise.ca\/content\/dam\/global-vehicle-images\/cars\/CHRY_200_2015.png"},{"Id":"2","Title":"Image1","Description":"Image1","CreatedDate":"2016-09-05 23:41:42","Order":"2","PhotoUrl":"https:\/\/www.enterprise.ca\/content\/dam\/global-vehicle-images\/cars\/CHRY_200_2015.png"}]"